# Can't rotate view around selected object (macbook pro)

Tags: objects, 3d-view

So I'm trying to figure out how to rotate my view around an object. When I press and hold the 3rd mouse wheel button to rotate my view, it freely rotates around a non-existent point rather than my selected object. This makes it very difficult

Comment: have you enabled the Rotate Around Selection option in the Preferences > Interface?

Comment: This has moved in 2.83 to Preferences > Navigation > Orbit around selection

Answer (score 1):

Blender rotates its view around an invisible, non-consistent point in space, which can be changed through several operations, including shifting the view with shift+mmb.

You can precisely position that point by

1. moving the view to the selected object (view > align view > view selected)
2. centering the view to the 3d cursor (view > align view > center view to cursor)

[image]

You can add a single-button shortcut to both these options, allowing you quickly set the center point with high precision.

Answer (score 0):

A good thing to do is to find your favorite vertex and tap the numpad's period key. When doing this, you're zeroing in your view to that specific vertex, as you're now zeroed in, you'll be able to orbit around it.